# How to get team avtar from DevOps api

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have tried to get team details using DevOps API, And I can get it but unable to get team Avtar/image, In response there is only text information, no descriptor available

I am using this way to get it..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Can you please guide me how can I get team Avtar/image ???

Comment: Does my answer work for you? Do you need any additional help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Subject Query from Azure DevOps API Graph

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/subject%20query/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Define the body like this:

```
{
    "query": "Your Group Name",
    "subjectKind": [ "Group" ]
}
```

The descriptor is at the end of each item in a result.

Then use it in belov request to get avatar

```
https://dev.azure.com/(Organization)/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/(descriptor)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,   It is possible to get project avatar like team avatar ?

Answer (score 2):

> How to get team avtar from DevOps api

In the security of Azure Devops, `subjectDescriptor` is user's `SID`. It used as identification when operating some security control. This parameter can **uniquely identify** the same graph subject across both Accounts and Organizations.

To get it, just use the following [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

From its response body, you can get the `descriptor` value of corresponding user.

[image]

Next, you can pass the corresponding `descriptor` value as `subjectDescriptor` into REST API [Avatars - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/avatars/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/Subjects/{subjectDescriptor}/avatars?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

In addition, the return result of above REST API is content of the image, in order to get the image of the avatar, we need provide the parameter `format=png`:

[image]

**Update:**

> this api for user avtar... i want to get project avtar

To get the project avtar, we need to get the `subjectDescriptor` of the project. We could use the REST API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/descriptors/{Teams Id}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

To get the `Teams Id`, we could use the [Teams - Get All Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get%20all%20teams?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/teams?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Then get the Id of the descriptor for the teams project:

[image]

Now, we could get the project avtar:

[image]

Comment: this api for user avtar...  i want to get project avtar

Comment: @Umang, Got it. I have updated the answer, please check if it helps you.

Comment: @Umang, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?